# C++ map insert -- replace existing element

Tags: c++

So I have a map of strings to objects, and I want to maintain the objects in alphabetical order. At first I did the following.

```
const auto &insertItr = m.insert(std::pair(text, objectPtr));
```

Thus, when I am inserting into the map, I want the insertion index, which I can get by subtracting the returned iterator from `m.begin()`. However, if the key `text` already exists in the map, then the object is not replaced like I intend, and the iterator instead points to the already existing object, which is not what I want.

While I could do

```
m[text] = objectPtr;
const auto &insertItr = m.find(text);
```

or

```
m.erase(m.find(text));
const auto &insertItr = m.insert(std::pair(text, objectPtr));
```

That is 2 operations, and I was wondering if there was 1 operation which would achieve the same result.

Thanks!

Comment: "_I want the insertion index_" - Just out of curiosity: What is that going to be used for? I don't think `std::distance(m.begin(), insertItr);` is a cheap operation when using `map` iterators.

Comment: I'm writing a GUI to hold some text items in a vertical list, and I wanted the text items to be in alphabetical order. Hmmm, I assumed the operation would be constant time, because I thought the iterators could just be subtracted.

Comment: No, the complexity is linear unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`std::map::insert_or_assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign)

```
auto insertItr = m.insert_or_assign(text, objectPtr).first;
```

This function returns **both** the iterator, and a `bool` indicating whether an insertion occurred.

Comment: isn't that overload return `std::pair<iterator, bool>`?

Answer (score 3):

If you can compile with C++17 you can use [`std::map::insert_or_assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign)

```
const auto &insertItr = m.insert_or_assign(text, objectPtr);
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks!! I thought I looked at the API carefully, dunno how I missed this. Thanks!